# Checking If a Number is Special Prime

Tags: haskell, primes

I am trying to create a program that prints special prime numbers in Haskell
`isSpecialPrime ::  Integer -> Bool` . The function should return if a number is a special prime number or not. A special prime number is a prime number that can be written as the sum of two neighboring prime numbers and 1. An example for a special prime number is 19 = 7 + 11 + 1.

I have managed to check if a number is prime or not here :

```
isPrime ::  Integer -> Bool

isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n 
 | (length [x | x <- [2 .. n-1],  n  `mod` x == 0]) > 0 = False
 | otherwise = True
```

Any ideas to tweak the code to return only the **Special Primes**

The output put should be something similar to this

```
> isSpecialPrime 19
True
```

Comment: You can do a simple linear search: start with a list of primes, and check the sum of each adjacent pair until it either equals your input minus one, or exceeds the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an aux function, you can do it like:

```
isPrime ::  Integer -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n 
 | (length [x | x <- [2 .. n-1],  n  `mod` x == 0]) > 0 = False
 | otherwise = True 

isSpecialPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isSpecialPrime 1 = False
isSpecialPrime x =  
 let firstNeighboring = findNeighbore x in
 isSpecialPrime' x firstNeighboring

isSpecialPrime' :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
isSpecialPrime' _ 0 = False 
isSpecialPrime' p x =  
 let firstNeighboring = findNeighbore x in
 let secondNeighboring = findNeighbore firstNeighboring in
 if (1 + firstNeighboring + secondNeighboring) == p
 then True
 else isSpecialPrime' p firstNeighboring

findNeighbore 0 = 0
findNeighbore x = if isPrime (x-1) then x-1 else findNeighbore (x-1)

primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve (2 : [3, 5..])
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

As an example:

```
filter isSpecialPrime $ take 40 primes
=> [13,19,31,37,43,53,61,79,101,113,139,163,173]
```

A little optimization:

```
isSpecialPrime' :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
isSpecialPrime' _ 1 = False 
isSpecialPrime' p x =
 let firstNeighboring = findNeighbore x in
 let secondNeighboring = findNeighbore firstNeighboring in
 let sumNeigh = secondNeighboring + firstNeighboring in
 if (p `div` 3) > sumNeigh
  then False else 
  if (1 + sumNeigh) == p
  then True
  else isSpecialPrime' p firstNeighboring
```

example:

```
filter isSpecialPrime $ take 100 primes
=> [13,19,31,37,43,53,61,79,101,113,139,163,173,199,211,223,241,269,277,331,353,373,397,457,463,509,521,541]
```